# Kotlin says Variable must be initialised

Tags: kotlin

What's wrong with this code?

[image]

I have initialised the `_children` variable but Kotlin compiler still asks me to initialize it. Confused as to what went wrong.

Comment: Please use a code block to provide your code to allow others to reproduce the problem without needing to type everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a property in another property's intializer before it has been declared. So move the declaration of `_children` above `children`.

Comment: Also since ``_children`` is lazy, you probably want to make ``children`` lazy too, i.e. ``override val children: List<ASTNode>? by lazy { _children }`` (at which point a separate ``_children`` property is basically redundant). If you don't, initialising ``children`` will immediately call ``_children``'s lazy delegate, so it gets set at construction time anyway, and the ``lazy`` is pointless